# The word "Description" causes ajax upload to 403

Tags: ajax, upload

I have been using Ajax for some time successfully in various ways. One use is for uploading of data, using

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type : "POST",
    url : encodeURI("savetext.php?..."),
    data : {
        data: csvData
    },
    success: function(data3) {},
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {}
});
```

The string csvData is created as lines of semi-colon - separated data, with lines terminated by '\r\n'.

Recently I have had a problem where I receive a 403 Forbidden on doing the upload.

After a long period of investigation [max file size, Cross-Origin, newline characters, ajax() parameters etc] and trial and error, I have concluded that the the problem is simply that I have the string ";Descri" within csvData.

I found this by splicing csvData in various places. ";Descr" seems to be not a problem but ";Descri" does in every position it occurs. I have not identified if it is a substring of ";Descri" that is the problem. I have now solved the problem completely with a kluge by replacing the word 'Description' in my data by 'Designation'.

This seems a very odd situation. Have I done something wrong? What can I do to ensure that I can include ";Descri" within my data in future?

Answer (score 0):

403 issue solution try adding this in htaccess

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of time I just deleted the word Description from my data, and the problem went away. However a few months later comething similar happened (but with a different trigger text) and I asked this question on the Webmasters site: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115890/how-can-file-content-affect-whether-its-uploading-gets-a-403-error

The (unsatisfactory) answer is given there.